# What is the run-time efficiency and space efficiency of this piece of code?

Tags: java

```
public void place(T item, int x, int y) {
    checkValidInputs(x, y);
    grid[x-1][y-1] = item;
}
```

where

```
private void checkValidInputs(int x, int y) {
    if ((rows < x || x < 0) || (columns < y || y < 0)) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Position must be within the grid");
    }
}
```

My anaylsis says that it is O(x*y) as checkValidInputs is O(1) and place is considered O(x*y)?

However, I am a bit stuck of the space efficiency, how would I determine this?

Comment: It's all O(1) because there is no *n* that affects space or time complexity. Why would you think `place()` is O(xy)?

Comment: is there a loop that calls place, that is not included in the code snippet

Comment: What do you recon takes space in this method ? the arguments ?

Comment: Thank you, I think what was confusing @shmosel is that:

public RectangularGrid(int x, int y) {
  grid = (T[][]) new Object[x][y];
 }

This would would x*y time, no? Because it has to create x*y arrays. In addition the space efficiency would also be x*y.

Comment: That's mostly correct, but you didn't include that code in your question.

Comment: I know. Thank you for your help :).

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is O(1) because there aren't any loops and this code will always take one form two amounts of time to execute depending if exception is thrown or not - but this case also fits the O(1) complexity, so in general this code in all cases is O(1).

Comment: Thank you, I think what was confusing is that:

public RectangularGrid(int x, int y) {
  grid = (T[][]) new Object[x][y];
 }

This would would x*y time, no? Because it has to create x*y arrays. In addition the space efficiency would also be x*y.

Comment: @LachlanGear Yes I think, that the complxity of creation of `(x*y)` array is `O(x*y)`. Of course that arrays take exactly the same amount of memory as they are declared to take.